# How to access the source code of wilcox.test function in the base package "stats" in R?

Tags: r

I wanted to access the source code of the `wilcox.test` function in R (my R GUI: Revolution R Enterprise).

From the console:

```
> wilcox.test
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("wilcox.test")
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

From Object Browser, right-click `wilcox.test` in stats package, and then clicking "edit" revealed:

```
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("wilcox.test")
```

I wanted to know the source code since sometimes the `wilcox.test` command produced a value "V=...", sometimes it produced "W=...". The help file of `wilcox.test` does not explain what is V and W. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I want a solution that requires no downloading R source code from CRAN or elsewhere; i.e., I want a solution within GUI (especially, Revo R Ent).

Comment: @zx8754 The link you gave does not mention V and W. does not clarify them.

Comment: @rbm, I wanted to know within GUI solution. Otherwise, going to CRAN, and unzipping, bla, bla, of course one can obtain with that long way.

Comment: You asked for source code, the link provided has a solution in the comments on how to see the source code...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a quick approach. Whenever you see `methods`, it means the function you call is a generic function. So do the following to list all methods it supports:

```
> methods(wilcox.test)
[1] wilcox.test.default* wilcox.test.formula*
```

Then you can try:

```
stats:::wilcox.test.default
```

or:

```
stats:::wilcox.test.formula
```

To print the function body into your R console.

Comment: Thx Oops. The `methods(wilcox.test)` produced [[ [1] wilcox.test.default* wilcox.test.formula* Non-visible functions are asterisked ]]. `stats:::wilcox.test.default` gave the exact long source code. `stats:::wilcox.test.formula` seems to be useful as well.